# XNA Keyboard.GetState() Not returning all keys pressed

Tags: c#, xna, keyboard

I am learning XNA (v. 4.0), and I'm working on moving a sprite around with the arrow keys on the keyboard, along with making the character sprint when space is held.

Below is my code to determine what keys are pressed:

```
currentKBState = Keyboard.GetState();

bool right = currentKBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right);
bool left = currentKBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left);
bool up = currentKBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up);
bool down = currentKBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down);
bool space = currentKBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", right, left, up, down, space));
```

The problem is that I cannot get all 5 to be pressed at the same time.  Sometimes only two will register.  For example, if I hold Up, Down, and Left, it only says that up and down are true, no matter how long I hold the three keys.  I want to be able to handle no matter what combination is pressed.  Why does it not register all the buttons that are being pressed?  Is there a different way I need to do it?

Comment: This probably is caused by the keyboard you own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not a code problem. It's a limitation of the keyboard hardware.

Cheap keyboards detect two concurrent key-presses reliably, but can already fail at certain combinations of three keys.

See [Rollover (key)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29)

> Modern keyboards detect ghosting, and instead of registering a fourth key, they will ignore the third key, which is known as jamming. Which keys jam when pressed together differs between brands and models of keyboards. Due to the keyboard matrix most consumer keyboards use, jamming and ghosting often occur when three out of four keys in a square block on the matrix are pressed, such as QASW or JKUI.

Comment: I found a site that said to test this by holding both shift keys and typing "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", and my keyboard got this..."HE QUIK BROWN FO JUPS OER HE LA DOG".  So that would appear to be the problem.  Thank you!  I've been trying to debug this for an hour. (will accept answer in 5 minutes)

Comment: THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG. Interestingly enough, my keyboard handles this fine but wont handle 3 keys within a block.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil As wikipedia says, the matrix depends on the brand of key-board. For good keyboards often support any 6 keys at once without issues. Hardware wise they often could go beyond that, but [unlike PS/2 USB is limited to 6 key rollover by default](http://winhlp.com/node/659).

Comment: Interesting, I just tried it and got `THKBNFJSTHLAYDG`, these cheap laptop keyboards I guess

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

```
Keys[] currentPressedKeys = currentKeyboardState.GetPressedKeys();
```

and then loop over Keys and check if some is pressed